How to overcome file lock error when using Arelle with Python?
installed arelle with pip install arelle-release. Mandatory dependencies seem to be present.
After importing and initialising Cntlr, I attempted to load the target document but I am receiving a filelock timeout.
I am a beginner with Arelle and have struggled to find step-by-step walkthroughs of how to get it up and running. Would appreciate if anyone might be able to point out solutions / obvious errors in what I attempted.
I'd also appreciate if someone could point me toward a detailed breakdown of how to make use of this package.
I tried the following:
from arelle import Cntlr, ModelManager

my_cont = Cntlr.Cntlr()
my_model_manager = my_cont.modelManager
my_model_xbrl = my_model_manager.load('the_doc.html')

But I am receiving the following error:
File "C:\Users\me\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\filelock.py", line 278, in acquire
    raise Timeout(self._lock_file)
filelock.Timeout: The file lock 'C:\Users\me\AppData\local\Arelle\cache\https\xbrl.some_char.xsd.lock' could not be acquired.
[Finished in 31.0s]


where 'xbrl.some_char.xsd.lock' is a placeholder
